# How to remove all subfolders that contain certain file and do not contain other file

Tags: linux, find, rm

I want to remove all direct subfolders of the working directory that contain the file `core.properties.unloaded` and **do not contain** the file `core.properties`. I know this must be a combination of `find` and `rm`. But how to combine?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting like so

```
$ find . -name "*"
.
./dir1
./dir1/core.properties.unloaded
./dir2
./dir2/core.properties
./dir3
./dir3/core.properties
./dir3/core.properties.unloaded
```

I ran this

```
for i in `find -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name "core.properties.unloaded" | awk -F'/' '{print $2}'`
do
  if [ ! -f "$i"/core.properties ]; then 
    rm -rf "$i"
  fi
done
```

And then the find command demonstrates that only dir1 was removed (the other two directories contain `core.properties` or do not contain `core.properties.unloaded`) -

```
$ find . -name "*"
```

.
   ./dir2
   ./dir2/core.properties
   ./dir3
   ./dir3/core.properties
   ./dir3/core.properties.unloaded